# MooTools vs Prototype & script. aculo.us

Tags: mootools, prototypejs, javascript-framework

1. Can we use MooTools AND Prototype & script. aculo.us, both in single project ?
2. Is there any problem occurs if we use both framework in single project ?
3. Is there any adapter, which help us to use both framework in single project ?

Answer (score 3):

1. No, cause both mootools and prototyp extending native javascript objeccts like string and array.
2. The last script will override the extending the first scrript does. So both frameworks have an Array.each function, and if an script. aculo.us script try do use each but mootools was inserted after prototyp script. aculo.us will use mootools each. Maybe it works but you cant trust anything.
3. I don't know any adapter.

Btw it isn't a good idea to mix frameworks. First there is an overhead in script load. Second the every framework is build with an specific goal in mind, like jquery is more dom related and easy to use, mootools prototyp are more in the oop business, they all cover most common task. So there is no need to have more then one solution for array.each.

Comment: You can have Mootools and JQuery side by side if you wished but ideally you should just stick to the one framework (*cough* Mootools hint hint)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Prototype and Mootools side by side, because recent MooTools version includes the mechanism [which detects the existence of $ function.](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/)

However there is very little point in using both frameworks in one project - both have simillar capabilities (extensive DOM manipulation and some goodies which extend JS core like OOP).

I found both frameworks quite simillar, and honestly if one of them can do something - the other one can surely do it as well.